# Unusual Custom Post Type pagination problems in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I've been reading and searching all night. I've had issues with CPT pagination before but this one is really making me crazy. I uploaded the site I'm building to http://koovay.com/Kingship/ . 
Currently version 3.7.1 . My original code was:

```
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=20&post_type=portfolio'.'&paged='.$paged); ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
$featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
$permalink = get_permalink( $id );
?>
```

-- Loop stuff --

```
<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav class="paged text-center">
<?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>

<?php 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Im using Custom Post Types UI and created my CPT as such:

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_portfolio');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_portfolio() {
register_post_type('portfolio', array(
'label' => 'Portfolio',
'description' => 'Your portfolio for showcasing yo bitch ass work!',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'works', 'with_front' => 1),
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'menu_position' => '5',
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
'taxonomies' => array('category'),
'labels' => array (
'name' => 'Portfolio',
'singular_name' => 'Work',
'menu_name' => 'Portfolio',
'add_new' => 'Add Work',
'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work',
'edit' => 'Edit',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Work',
'new_item' => 'New Work',
'view' => 'View Work',
'view_item' => 'View Work',
'search_items' => 'Search Portfolio',
'not_found' => 'No Portfolio Found',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolio Found in Trash',
'parent' => 'Parent Work',
)
) ); }
```

I read a post regarding changing rewrite name to something other than the CPT name so I changed it to "work".

But this triggered a 404. I've tried a few alt. versions of running the loop and pagination I can post.

Honestly, I am really hoping someone can shoot me some help. Going crazy...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used [GenerateWP](http://generatewp.com/post-type/) to create the code below. It should work.

```
if ( ! function_exists('Portfolio') ) {
```

function Portfolio() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Portfolio Items',
    'singular_name'       => 'Portfolio',
    'menu_name'           => 'Portfolio ',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Portfolio ',
    'all_items'           => 'All Portfolio ',
    'view_item'           => 'View Portfolio ',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Portfolio ',
    'add_new'             => 'New Portfolio ',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Portfolio ',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Portfolio ',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Portfolio ',
    'not_found'           => 'No Portfolio Items FOund',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No products found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'portfolio ',
    'description'         => 'portfolio ',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'portfolio ', $args );
```

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'Portfolio', 0 );

}